# What are some best practices for UI design in virtual reality?

Tags: interaction-design, human-eye, hud

First person perspective games typically feature a four-corner HUD-based approach for displaying peripheral info to the player i.e. health bar, mana, radar, etc.

This looks awful in VR. What the player sees is four floating 2D squares, which, not only look bad, but can also cause eye strain when looking between the world and an occluding HUD element. Especially when placed in the visual limit range (see diagram).

[image: From MozVR]
<sub>(source: [mozvr.com](http://mozvr.com/posts/quick-vr-prototypes/human-visual-field.jpg))</sub>

I've seen some creative solutions for hierarchical menus that involve hand motion-tracking (Leap Motion and Dexmo come to mind). Approaches like this opt out of a HUD altogether and anchor information to objects in the world. In the case of the Leap Motion/Dexmo the player's motion-tracked arm is the anchor for the menu.

I want to see what I can (and what others) get away with in displaying basic information that *always* remains within the player's visual field range.

So, instead of positioning planar HUD elements in the visual limit range maybe display them as close to the center around the reticle. For a health/mana meter: Make it radial, invisible when there is no change, and semitransparent when there is a change to display.

What do you think of this approach? Are there examples yet of design practices in VR that rethink HUD conventions without anchoring? Generally I think they'd be minimalist solutions like the one I outlined above.

And, to note, I understand that some things have to go. I've yet to see a good solution for radar (although I like what Bungie's done with traditional 'breadcumb' radar in their latest game, Destiny. This could be adapted to VR).

Comment: Welcome to UX.se. While the topic is interesting, I'm afraid that the question as it stands doesn't lend itself to answering as it's too broad. Please edit it down to a specific question or it is likely to be closed.

Comment: Interesting question but nearly impossible to answer on this 2D display we are communicating on.  :)

Comment: @JohnGB Thank you for the welcome. And I will edit this down soon. I am on mobile at the moment.

Comment: @DaveAlger I should have realized that before posting. Sorry.

Comment: @SolCrenshaw I'm closing this for now, but once you've edited it, let me know either in chat or by mentioning me in a comment here and I'll re-evaluate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how easy or smooth this would be to implement, but one intuitive possibility that comes to mind is to have these elements show up when the user tilts their head down and to one side or the other—like they would have to do if they were playing a 2D game on a giant screen right in front of them. Then the HUD elements wouldn't obstruct the view of anything at eye level.

Alternatively, or in addition to the above, there could be a button to press or a hand motion to show or hide them.

Combining these two ideas, another intuitive option would be to display these elements when the user looks down and makes a "looking at your watch" hand motion.